# How to disable php-ext after using docker-php-ext-enable?

Tags: php, docker

I konw remove `docker-php-ext-enable some-ext` and rebuild container can resolve it, but is there any other way to do?

Comment: get rid of that extension from the php.ini from loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Docker, the recommended way is as you've described.

You should remove the unwanted extensions from your `Dockerfile` and then rebuild.

The Docker Containers should be seen as "temporary" and nothing should be stored in the container that needs to persist. If you are that's a Docker config/implementation problem rather than a problem with Docker.

---

To answer the question asked, the answer is the same as every other install of PHP, log in to the container and comment out the extension in the `php.ini` file and then restart the PHP service. As this varies from install to install I am/we are unable to give you any guidance on the exact process without further information.